# hileras funcion insertar un caracter

Tags: java

estoy tratando de insertar un caracter de ultimo en la primera palabra cuando ingreso en la hilera una palabra de dimension 1 osea una "y" o "a" me saca error y no me hace nada en metodo adjunto mi meto

```
public void cambiarUltimo(char pCar) {
        Nodo p, q;
        q = new Nodo(pCar);
        p = cab.RetornaLiga();

        while (p != null && p.GetCaracter() != ' ') {
            if (p.RetornaLiga().GetCaracter() == ' ') {
                p.AsignaLiga(q);
                q.AsignaLiga(p.RetornaLiga());
            }
        }

    }
```

no me saca error la cosas es que no me hace nada como si se quedara en el metodo y no saliera 
public class Nodo {

```
private char car;
private Nodo liga;

public Nodo(char pCar) {
    car = pCar;
    liga = null;
}

public char GetCaracter() {
    return car;
}

public void AsignaLiga(Nodo pLiga) {
    liga = pLiga;
}

public Nodo RetornaLiga() {
    return liga;
}
```

}

Comment: comparte el código de tu clase nodo, y dí exactamente en qué linea te marca error

Comment: edita tu respuesta y agrega el código, por los comentarios no se entiende

Comment: Ok qué se supone que tiene que hacer? como sabes si funciona o no si no haces ningún return ni un system? pon como estás haciendo las pruebas, un resultado deseado y el que te da

Comment: necesito ingresar una hilera por ejemplo yo ingreso "hola que hace" 
luego de eso me pregunte que caracter deseo insertar por ejemplo "R" cuando le ingrese ese caracter la hilera me debe qeudar asi de esta forma 
"holaR que hace"

Comment: ok aquí hay dos cosas, la primera es que liga se inicia como null, por lo que while (p != null && p.GetCaracter() != ' ') { nunca entra ya que no es diferente de null, la segunda el char es de un solo caracter, no puedes igualar un char a una caden

Comment: es que yo no lo quiero igualar y lo del null lo podria quitar? y cuando me encuentre el primer espacio en blanco entre al while?